# Is there a way to limit the number of gift cards that can be used in a single transaction?

Tags: checkout, gift-card

I am using Magento 2.4.2 and I am wondering if there is a way we can limit a customer to being able to use one gift card when they go to checkout?

Comment: No, You need customization for that.

Comment: giftcard can also redeem into storecredit in my account, you can't avoid customer from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

A around plugin for `\Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Giftcardaccount::addToCart` would suffice. You can see in that method already how Magento gets all the cards. You would just throw an exception of there was already a card in the quote.

The frontend would be a bit more complex as you would need to remove the UI that allows you to add cards. You could create a new block based on `\Magento\GiftCardAccount\Block\Checkout\Cart\Giftcardaccount` or a ViewModel (see https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html) to get the quote, and just not render that block if there are already cards applied.